# How to add multiple GeoJsonLayer runtime and get click event in android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, highlight

I am trying to add multiple `GeoJsonLayer` run time my requirement is on responce of api i have to highlight multiple countries in map which is working fine but i am not getting click event multiple layer i know only single layer click is only suppored by android but is ther a any way to add multiple layer and get separate click event of all event

this is my code

```
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonLayer
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonPolygonStyle
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*


class MapsNewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener {
            val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
            val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1)
            if (addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
                val country: String? = addresses[0].getCountryName()
                Log.e(TAG, "country is ${country.toString()}")
                Toast.makeText(this, country.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

        val madrid = LatLng(40.416775, -3.70379)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(madrid, 3f))

        retrieveFileFromUrl()
    }

    private fun retrieveFileFromUrl() {
        DownloadGeoJsonFile().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xomena-so/so41431384/master/app/src/main/res/raw/es_geojson.json")
        DownloadGeoJsonFile().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xomena-so/so41431384/master/app/src/main/res/raw/us_geojson.json")
    }

    inner class DownloadGeoJsonFile : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, GeoJsonLayer?>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): GeoJsonLayer? {
            try {
                // Open a stream from the URL
                val stream = URL(params[0]).openStream()
                var line: String?
                val result = StringBuilder()
                val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
                while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    // Read and save each line of the stream
                    result.append(line)
                }

                // Close the stream
                reader.close()
                stream.close()

                return GeoJsonLayer(mMap, JSONObject(result.toString()))
//                return JSONObject(result.toString())
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GeoJSON file could not be read")
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject")
            }
            return null
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(layer: GeoJsonLayer?) {
            layer?.let { addGeoJsonLayerToMap(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun addGeoJsonLayerToMap(layer: GeoJsonLayer) {
        val style: GeoJsonPolygonStyle = layer.defaultPolygonStyle
        style.fillColor = R.color.map_highlight
        style.strokeColor = R.color.map_highlight_border
        style.strokeWidth = 1f
        layer.addLayerToMap()

        layer.setOnFeatureClickListener {
            Log.e(TAG, "layer click ${it.getProperty("title")}")
            Log.e(TAG, "layer click Data = = = ${Gson().toJson(it)}")
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Feature clicked: " + it.getProperty("title"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

        }
    }
}
```

this is what I am getting

[image]

I am also getting a country name in `toast` on click of any other country but not getting a country name or click event in `setOnFeatureClickListener` or `setOnMapClickListener` on click of the highlighted part

so how do I get data on click of highlighted part in map?

Please help me how do I achieve this

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the best solution but if you disable the click of the layer then you will get an event in `setOnMapClickListener`

so I added this to get click event `style.isClickable = false` this will pervert the layer click event

```
val style: GeoJsonPolygonStyle = layer.defaultPolygonStyle
        style.fillColor = R.color.map_highlight
        style.strokeColor = R.color.map_highlight_border
        style.strokeWidth = 1f
        style.isClickable = false // this will pervert setOnFeatureClickListener so  mMap.setOnMapClickListener work
        layer.addLayerToMap()
```

you will receieve click event in this part

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener {
            val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
            val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1)
            if (addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
                val country: String? = addresses[0].getCountryName()
                Log.e(TAG, "country is ${country.toString()}")
                Toast.makeText(this, country.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

this is working for me please do correct me if I am doing some wrong